# How to solve these two double inequalities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have these inequalities, which are suppose to be equivalent, but I can't find out how.
\begin{align}
 0&\leq z-x\leq 2 \tag 1\\
 z-2&\leq x\leq z \tag 2
\end{align}

According to Wolfram Alpha they have the same solution, $x \leq z \leq x+2$.

I try to go from $(1)$ by adding $2x$:
\begin{align}
2x \leq z+x \leq 2 +2x \tag 3
\end{align}
And add $-z$ so:
\begin{align}
2x - z \leq x \leq 2+2x -z \tag 4
\end{align}
But I'm stuck here, this isn't near $(2)$...

Comment: $z-2\leq x\leq z\Longrightarrow -2\leq x-z \leq 0 \Longrightarrow -(-2) \geq -(x-z) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> \begin{align}
>  0&\leq z-x\leq 2 \tag 1\\
>  z-2&\leq x\leq z \tag 2
> \end{align}

You have,

$$\begin{align}z-x≥0&\implies z≥x\\
&\implies x≤z\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}z-x≤2&\implies z≤2+x\\
&\implies z-2≤x\end{align}$$

This means,

$$0≤z-x≤2\iff z-2≤x≤z.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint. There are four inequalities here. Treat them two at a time. Start with
$$
0  \le z-x
$$
and see what you can do to show that it's equivalent to part of (2).

Then ...